# Не работает счетчик Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, счетчики

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import shuffle


def main_app():
    global numbers_questions, new_data
    numbers_questions = int(main_answer.get())
    if numbers_questions > 50 or numbers_questions < 1:
        messagebox.showerror('Ошибка', 'Введите число от 1 до 50!')
    else:
        shuffle(all_data)
        new_data = all_data[:numbers_questions]
        shuffle(new_data)
        que_1()


def que_1():
    global i, numbers_correct, numbers_questions
    answer = Entry()
    answer.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER, width=200, height=35)

    ans = answer.get().upper()

    main_title.configure(text=new_data[i][0])

    if i == numbers_questions-1:
        main_btn.configure(command=the_end)
    else:
        main_btn.configure(command=que_2)

    if ans == new_data[i][1][new_data[i][0]]:
        numbers_correct += 1

    i += 1


def que_2():
    global i, numbers_correct, numbers_questions
    answer_1 = Entry()
    answer_1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER, width=200, height=35)

    ans = answer_1.get().upper()
    main_title.configure(text=new_data[i][0])

    if i == numbers_questions-1:
        main_btn.configure(command=the_end)
    else:
        main_btn.configure(command=que_1)

    if ans == new_data[i][1][new_data[i][0]]:
        numbers_correct += 1
    i += 1


def the_end():
    global numbers_correct
    main_title.configure(text='Ваш результат: {0}/{1}'.format(numbers_correct, numbers_questions))
    main_btn.place_forget()
    a = Entry()
    a.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER, width=200, height=35)


root = Tk()  # Поле
root.title('Практика')  # Название окна
root.geometry('700x500')  # Размеры
root.configure(bg='#9999CC')  # Задний фон

all_data = [...]

i = 0
numbers_correct = 0

main_title = Label(root, text='Введите количество вопросов', font='Times 26', bg='#9999CC')
main_answer = Entry()
main_btn = Button(root, text='Ответить!', command=main_app)
main_title.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=CENTER)
main_answer.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER, width=200, height=35)
main_btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER, width=200, height=35)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: В чем выражается это "не работает"?

Comment: пишет, что правильных ответов 0

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас не срабатывает условие if ans == new_data[i][1][new_data[i][0]]  Точнее сказать не могу, т.к. вы скрыли ваши данные, на которых вы это запускаете. Но вообще, правая часть этого сравнения выглядит ну очень странно и, скорее всего, у вас какая-то путаница именно там.

Comment: массив состоит из таких элементов ('Вопрос 1', {'Вопрос 1': 'Б'}, 'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г'),
('Вопрос 2', {'Вопрос 2': 'В'}, 'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г')